# symfony2: change url route parameter with a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need to be able to let the user select some parameters in an application. So I created a form, which let's the user e.g. select a year.

I changed the action of the form to `GET` and changed it's `name` to `null`. When the form is submitted this adds a classic url-query-string-parameter to the url.

However I'm using symfony-routes and I'd like to let the result of submitting the form be changing a route-parameter.

Here is an example for clarity: Suppose I'd use a route like this one:

```php
@Route("/assignment/{year}", name="assignment")
function indexAction($year){...}
```

Then I'd like to change the year route-parameter through submitting a form like this one.

```php
$this->get('form.factory').createNamedBuilder(null, FormType::class)
  ->setAction('get')
  ->add('year', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => [2016 => 2016, 2022 => 2022]])
  ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

Is there a way to archive this without adding extra javascript?
What is the best way to choose if this can't be archived? Drop the route-parameter and just handle the form-data "manually"?

Comment: Why do you need a form for this? Unless you have more than 1 parameter, you are better off using a dropdown ala Bootstrap and adding links with the appropriate year to each `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

If the form also is on the `/assignment/{year}` route, then this could be an idea.

In the `indexAction()` function, you can check to see if the form has been submitted, and if it is, redirect back to the route with the year selected in the form.

```
//SomethingController.php
public function indexAction($year, Request $request)
{
    //...
    $form = $this->get('form.factory'). // You know the rest

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        // Do some stuff depending on values of form if you'd like, and then

        $this->redirectToRoute('assignment', ['year' => $year]);
    }
}
```